# How to use and set custom env variables in vue electron

Tags: vue.js, electron, environment-variables

How i can add some custom env variables in my electron app? I want use them to store api keys and other things that I don't want to write directly into the code. I'm using vue and electron.

If I understand well I need to create a new `.env` file in the root of the vue electron project?

Comment: yes https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes i am sure it works the same in electron

Comment: Make sure to create several .env file (.env.local) for example, and make sure to store your API keys in the correct one. You don't want API keys to become part of your code repository, so check the Vue documentation thoroughly!

Comment: Thank you. If someone create a short answer I will accept it.

Answer (score -1):

[https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/environment-variables]

that's the documentation link for environment vars

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.